# Help identify this curly 60s style display font

Tags: font-identification

Help me please to find this twisted font.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Found it.  It's [Elephant Bells](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bagraphics/elephant-bells/):

[image: Elephant Bells font sample]